# Deploying grails app on jetty, 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE

Tags: java, grails, jetty

Hello I am trying to deploy my grails application to my newly installed jetty instance. I installed jetty on `ubuntu 12.04` with `apt-get install jetty` and it's running completely fine under port 8080.

Then I tried to deploy my small grails application by compiling it to a war-file and moving it to the standard `jetty_home/webapps` folder and restart jetty. Now the problem begins, whenever I go to my context path in the browser I get this:

```
HTTP ERROR: 503

Problem accessing /hello. Reason:

    SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
```

When I check the jetty logs it is almost completely empty except some logging errors?

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I can't get it to run my application which is just a hello-world app (I've tried with my real app before also). At first I thought it was because of openjre on the deployment machine but then I tried to compile it with openjdk and it still has the same results.

I have also tried to set the hello.war file under the `jetty:abs` user via chown command. The root app is deployed just like this and I see no reason why my app shouldn't work.

I've checked some threads to see if my installation process is wrong somehow but I can't find any solution. There is no other errors logged. If I use `cat 2013_01_29.stderrout.log` it's empty. Please help me find a solution to my problem, I just want my app up and running asap.

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

Okay, I downloaded the jar file recommended and now I got some exception about permission denied on my applicationContext. I am still unsure how to continue since I'm kind of confused. I guess this means that jetty don't have the permission required to write in `/var/cache/jetty` ?

```
2013-01-29 23:31:27.885:INFO::jetty-6.1.24
2013-01-29 23:31:27.945:INFO::Deploy /etc/jetty/contexts/javadoc.xml -> org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler@ed42d08{/javadoc,file:/usr/share/jetty/javadoc}
2013-01-29 23:31:28.008:INFO::Extract file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/hello.war to /var/cache/jetty/data/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_hello.war__hello__.yjv6m1/webapp
2013-01-29 23:31:28.051:WARN::Failed startup of context org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext@7786df0f{/hello,file:/var/lib/jetty/webapps/hello.war}
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/cache/jetty/data/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_hello.war__hello__.yjv6m1/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:209)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:160)
    at org.mortbay.resource.JarResource.extract(JarResource.java:215)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.resolveWebApp(WebAppContext.java:942)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.getWebInf(WebAppContext.java:800)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebInfConfiguration.configureClassLoader(WebInfConfiguration.java:62)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:457)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:156)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.doStart(HandlerCollection.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:985)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:194)
    at org.mortbay.start.Main.start(Main.java:534)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.start.daemon.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.apache.commons.daemon.support.DaemonLoader.start(DaemonLoader.java:243)
2013-01-29 23:31:28.078:INFO::NO JSP Support for , did not find org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet
2013-01-29 23:31:28.118:INFO::Opened /var/log/jetty/2013_01_29.request.log
2013-01-29 23:31:28.143:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
```

Comment: See this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951610/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Comment: Okay but how do I select only one of those jars? Kinda new to jetty configurations

Comment: Place this [jar](http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/pub/mirrors/maven2/org/slf4j/slf4j-nop/1.5.2/slf4j-nop-1.5.2.jar) in your `jetty-libs` directory

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I updated my question with more data. Do you know how to help me? :)

Comment: Okay, this is strange. Aren't grails supposed to package it automatically? In my project, the path is correct and when I used the command grails war I thought it should package the WEB-INF contents with it. It appears that the files doesn't exist (obviously) under /var/cache anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have write permission to unpack the war file - it's failing to write `/var/cache/jetty/data/Jetty_0_0_0_0_8080_hello.war__hello__.yjv6m1/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml`. The `java.io.FileNotFoundException` is confusing but the 
"Permission denied" message is telling you the real problem.

Either grant yourself write permission under the `/var/cache/jetty/data/` directory, or run Jetty as a user that has write permission, or change the directory where Jetty expands war files to a location you can write to.

Comment: I tried to give jetty full ownership but as soon as I do it it goes back to the root group. Do you know how I can change this behavior?