# Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: UnresolvedAddressException

Tags: eclipse, maven, dependencies, integration

I have integrated Maven with Eclipse and trying to create a maven project. Every time i am trying to create project, its POM.xml shows error.

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>     - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile
>   (execution:    default-compile, phase: compile)
>     - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile
>   (execution:    default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)
>     - CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its
>   dependencies       could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:2.3.2:
>   ArtifactResolutionException:       Failure to transfer
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from
>   htt:///repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local
>   repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update
>   interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error:
>   Could not transfer     artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:2.3.2 from/to
>   central (htt:///repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to htt://
>   repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/2.3.2/maven-compiler-plugin-2.3.2.pom

If I try to run maven-install or any of the maven run option. i get this error

> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>   SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation SLF4J:
>   See htt://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further
>   details. [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO]
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building CQ5 MyApp UI 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ Downloading:
>   http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom
>   [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 12.289s [INFO] Finished at: Thu Mar 14 14:39:09 IST
>   2013 [INFO] Final Memory: 1M/15M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.5 or
>   one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact
>   descriptor for
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not
>   transfer artifact
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to
>   central (htt://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): null to
>   htt://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.5/maven-resources-plugin-2.5.pom:
>   UnresolvedAddressException -> [Help 1] [ERROR]  [ERROR] To see the
>   full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>   [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>   [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible
>   solutions, please read the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginResolutionException

What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml ?.

Answer (score 18):

1. If you are working on windows like me, just go to C:\Users\Owner.m2\repository and delete all the files in it. Make sure to keep your eclipse close.
2. Open eclipse and right click on your project, then click on Maven and then in Update Project. A dialog window appears, make sure to have selected ‘clean projects’ and ‘update project configuration from pom.xml’ options.

That should erase all the errors in the project. :)

Answer (score 5):

You do not really have to delete everything from .m2\repository directory. Just the directories for 'problematic libraries', in your example YOUR_MAVEN_REPO.m2\repository\org\apache\maven\plugins\maven-compiler-plugin and delete 2.3.2 folder.

Then right click on the project in Eclipse and Maven->Update Project. You will probably get a different error and you have to repeat the procedure. Do it 3-4 times and it should be fine...

Answer (score 3):

Thank you all for you help and guidance. I got the error myself. I am in a proxy network and was required to set user id and password in settings.xml file of apache maven.

Comment: rDX can you paste the snippet for giving the credienital\

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may need to add the sl4j dependency in your pom file.  See here: [Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7951610/failed-to-load-class-org-slf4j-impl-staticloggerbinder)

Here is the depenedency from the dependency finder in CQ5.5:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.sling</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.apache.sling.commons.log</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3-R1232904</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps and good luck.